# Interface not responding after fresh install

Tags: user-interface

After trying Elementary Os Freya from my USB on my desktop computer (working perfectly), I installed it, following the installer. But after the first reboot, the graphical interface is completely buggy and doesn't always respond, which kinda prevents me from using it ...
Is there any know solution for this issue ?

Thanks !

EDIT: Apparently, I just have to log out and in again to make it work ...

Comment: This rarely happens to me andI cannot click anything.So I press CTRL + ALT + F1 and login and type `pkill wingpanel` and `pkill slingshot` and press CTRL + ALT + F7 to go back to the desktop